# How to replace text within a pdf file?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to replace text within a pdf file using Google Apps Script?

I am trying the following code without success on the replace, it seems like the string is encoded in a way I cannot understand.

```
  var pdfFile = DocsList.getFileById("pdf-doc-id");
  var asBlob = pdfFile.getBlob();
  var asString = asBlob.getDataAsString();
  var s2s = "old string";
  var s2r = "new string";
  var repString = asString.replace(s2s, s2r);
  var repBlob = Utilities.newBlob(repString).setContentType("application/pdf").setName("Testing");
  DocsList.createFile(repBlob);
```

EDIT1: I got an empty pdf back

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The last line of your code is wrong I guess... shouldn't it be `DocsList.createFile(repBlob);` ? otherwise it is indeed the original file ;-)

Comment: yes indeed, sorry I am a mess. I have updated the code... I am getting an empty Pdf instead. I feel is doable but I am lost with Blob

Comment: not sure itis doable... I tried but failed when converting string to pdf. I'm pretty curious to see if someone have a solution or if it is simply not possible to process pdf this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getDataAsString()` doesn't return the textual content of a PDF file, but instead a textual representation of the binary content of the file. That function works on any file, even those that don't have text (like images).

Unfortunately I don't think you can fully accomplish your goal with Apps Script. If you are able to import your PDF as a Google Document using the Drive UI, then you can use Apps Script's DocumentApp to modify the document and export it as a PDF.

Comment: then what to use if not google apps script?